# why is STL set comparator only specified via template?

Tags: c++, stl

The only way to supply custom comparator to the std::set container is via the template specialization.  Which means that the comparator detail will leak to all users of the set.  Is there a way around it and why such a strange decision choice was made?  Shouldn't I be able to have a method which returns a set ordered to my liking but w/o everyone having to know what the ordering is?

Comment: The set stores the comparator.  How would it store it if it does not know the type?

Comment: `std::set<T, std::function<bool(T, T)>>` seems close to what you want. You can plug a more or less arbitrary comparator into this at runtime.

Comment: Comparisons are really cheap operations for many types. Imposing a mandatory dynamic dispatch to make choice of order at run-time would cause significant performance degradation (that was certainly true at the time the class templates were defined but I'm pretty sure that is still true). You can choose to have a binary predicate which does dynamic dispatch, e.g., using `std::function<bool(T const&, T const&)>` if you feel you need t use different choices.

Comment: @Igor I don't think that would work because you have no way of actually assigning that function.

Comment: @zett42: `std::set` (and the other associative containers in the standard library) have a constructor overload taking the comparison object.

Comment: Igor/Dietmar why not answer?  I think this is good, thanks.

Comment: @Dietmar, cool! Another day on SO, learned something new. [And it actually works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2354d7491800d30).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many uses, the default choice of comparison, i.e., using `std::less<T>` which uses `a < b` works very well. This comparison doesn't do any dynamic dispatch which would allow a choice of order without affecting the type because the dynamic dispatch would likely cause a performance degradation. Adding a dynamic dispatch certainly caused a performance degradation at the time the interface was defined and I'd think it is still true and unlikely to go away entirely.

If you want to choose the order without affecting the type you can use `std::function<bool(T const&, T const&)>` (or `std::function<bool(T, T)>` if `T` happens to be a cheap to copy type like the built-in types). You'd need to specify the comparison object as a constructor argument in this case. For example:

```
std::set<int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> values{std::less<int>()};
```

Note that the above code uses curlies as otherwise it would be a function declaration rather than an object definition. Also note that assigning a `std:set<int, std::function<bool(int, int)>>` to another one with different comparison function will not work: the code would compile but the assignment will create a set which is incorrectly ordered. For example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> values1{std::less<int>()};
    values1.insert(1);
    values1.insert(2);
    values1.insert(3);
    std::set<int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> values2{std::greater<int>()};
    values2 = values1;
    for (auto v: values2) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

This prints the values in ascending order although it should print them in descending order.

Comment: [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a959d8227db4842) based on your idea. Almost the same except that I created some alias templates to make the solution easily reusable.

Comment: It would be interesting to compare performance of static vs. dynamic comparator.

Comment: @zett42: I added a benchmark for a dynamic comparison function to https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/cputube/blob/master/cpu/test/search-integer.cpp It indicates that the overhead for small sets is rather large. For large sets a visible impact remains but it isn't as significant. The main caveat with my results is that I currently have only access to a computer which isn't really suitable for doing interesting benchmarks but I'd think the results wouldn't be that different on a "real" computer.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments (igor and dietmar) you can do this via `std::function`:

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using Dynamic_set= std::set<T, std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)>>;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
   auto absSet = Dynamic_set<int>([](const auto&a, const auto&b){ return abs(a)<abs(b) ;});
   absSet.emplace(1);
   absSet.emplace(2);
   absSet.emplace(-1);
   std::cout << absSet.size() << std::endl;
}
```

prints `2`. Note that using auto as above avoids *most vexing parse* issues.

More general:

```
template<typename Key, typename Allocator = std::allocator<Key>>
using Dynamic_set= std::set<Key, std::function<bool(const Key&, const Key&)>, Allocator>;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e48db498d81f2945)

Comment: Great, but credits should be given to Dietmar who came up with this idea originally. So no vote from me.

Comment: This is not a new thing... I did give credit to the commenters and now also added their names.